# How to create a date with a format of "2008:05:30 15:56:01"

Tags: javascript

How can I create a date object with this date format?

Using `new Date("2008:05:30 15:56:01")` leads to an invalid date.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, clarify your question showing what you've tried and why you have a date with `:`  . can't you just replace the `:` form the date part with `/` before create the `new Date()` ?

Comment: You can call `new Date(year, monthIndex , day , hours , minutes)`, and it does not look so complicated to  _split_  `2008:05:30 15:56:01`  into individual parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Spread operator and a bit of string splitting to get the desired result:

```js
let dateFrom = "2008:05:30 15:56:01"

dateFrom = dateFrom.split(" "); // split time and date

let date = new Date(...dateFrom[0].split(":"), ...dateFrom[1].split(":"));

console.log(date)
```

In this line:

```
new Date(...dateFrom[0].split(":"), ...dateFrom[1].split(":"));
```

You use the spread operator and the split function to transform `"2008:05:30"` into `2008, 05, 30`, and `"15:56:01"` into `15, 56, 01`

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the first couple colons (`:`) with dashes (`-`) to make it close enough to ISO8601 format that the `new Date(...)` constructor will recognize it:

```
function dateFromGoofyFormat(str) {
  return new Date(str.replace(/:/g, function(_1, i) {
    return (i <= 7) ? '-' : ':';
  }));
}

dateFromGoofyFormat('2008:05:30 15:56:01');
// => Fri May 30 2008 15:56:01 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```